# Find and replace expression with repeated variable?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a list of items in a text file that look like this:

```
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc-Name="PCP0001 Protocol" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc-Name="PCR0001 Report" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc-Name="DCR0002 Review" group="FP Team"
```

I would like to expand the middle part to look like this:

```
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/PCP0001.Protocol.doc" Doc-Name="PCP0001 Protocol" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/PCR0001.Report.doc" Doc-Name="PCR0001 Report" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/DCR0002.Review.doc" Doc-Name="DCR0002 Review" group="FP Team"
```

In other words, I want to use the Doc-Name and add an URL in front of it and replace the spaces with ".".

Can someone help me with this?  I have literally 900 of these so sort thru.

Here is what I tried in NotePad++:

I used this Find expression:

```
Doc-Name=[^"]*"([^"]+)"[^"]
```

And used this Replace expression:

```
Doc="http://1.1.1.1/$1.doc" Doc-Name="$1"
```

This got me 90% there but not quite.  I don't know how to replace the spaces within $1 with periods.  This will finish the job and I need some help here.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What have you tried so far? What problems specifically have you run into? Please **edit your question** to include this information to help people answer you. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yep, reasonable, here is what I tried.  In NotePad++, I used this expression to find:  Doc-Name=[^"]*"([^"]+)"[^"] and then this expression to replace:  Doc="http://1.1.1.1/$1.doc" Doc-Name="$1"  This got me 90% there...but I don't know how to replace the spaces in the $1 with periods...  Need some help here.

Comment: i havent read the whole thing but if u capture something and want to replace something within a capture then you do a second regex. Also to replace a space with a period  find `[ ]` replace with `.`  (dot wouldnt have special meaning in the replace portion so wouldnt be escaped).. but you probably dont need two regexes for this

Comment: your find portion looks a bit odd, surely this will suffice `Doc-Name="([^"]*)"`   I dont have time to do the replace but it's replaced with `Doc=......... Doc-name=......`

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/VGRDo2v.png  find- `Doc-Name="([^"]*)"`  replace with- `Doc="http://1.1.1.1/$1" Doc-Name="$1"`   done in notepad++   Ah ok i see you want to do some other replace.. I have to go now , will look again later  hopefully somebody else will solve / help you with it sooner

Comment: Thanks Barlop, yes, you're right about the Find expression Doc-Name="([^"]*)", this is much simpler but it still gives me the same result.  It is not replacing the spaces in $1 with periods...like Doc="http://1.1.1.1/Some.Text.doc" Doc-Name="Some(space)Text"

Comment: yeah i'm not sure how to replace spaces within a portion.. 'cos as you say.. how do you capture a repeating expression! (or a replace on a portion). You ask a good question but you could make your question much simpler/better if you just started with `Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/PCP0001 Protocol" Doc-Name="PCP0001 Protocol" group="FP Team"`  and asked how do you replace the spaces within doc="..." with period. So show that thing as your start.. and show what you want. `Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/PCP0001.Protocol.doc" Doc-Name="PCP0001 Protocol" group="FP Team"`

Comment: and point out that there could be any number of space in the doc="..."    Many times we use regex with a programming language, so having captured something one can work on that.

Comment: thanks, well...  I'm not sure which way to ask the question is simpler....  I'm just asking what I started with and how far I got...  May be there are other answers out there.

Comment: judging by your so-called answer, you were actually only asking about deleting one space , rather than what you spoke of "repeated variable", by which it seems you meant "repeated pattern "  like   (non-spaces, spaces) repeated. And removing spaces from there.  As it stands, what you really wanted, deleting one space, is obvious and only really useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way that works if there are more than one space:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Doc-Name="([^"\h]+)\h+([^"\h]+)(?:\h+([^"\h]+))?(?:\h+([^"\h]+))?(?:\h+([^"\h]+))?(?:\h+([^"\h]+))?"`
- Replace with: `Doc="http://1.1.1.1/$1.$2(?3.$3:)(?4.$4:)(?5.$5:)(?6.$6:).doc" $0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
Doc-Name="          : literally
([^"\h]+)           : group 1, 1 or more any character that is not a double quote or horizontal space
\h+                 : 1 or more horizontal space
([^"\h]+)           : group 2, 1 or more any character that is not a double quote or horizontal space
(?:                 : non capture group
  \h+               : 1 or more horizontal space
  ([^"\h]+)         : group 2, 1 or more any character that is not a double quote or horizontal space
)?                  : end group, optional
(?:\h+([^"\h]+))?   : same as above
(?:\h+([^"\h]+))?   : same as above
(?:\h+([^"\h]+))?   : same as above
....... as many as you need
"                   : double quote
```

**Replacement:**

```
Doc="http://1.1.1.1/    : literally
$1                      : content of group 1
.                       : a dot
$2                      : content of group 2
(?3.$3:)                : conditional replacement, if group 3 exists replace by itself preceded with a dot
(?4.$4:)                : same as above for group 4
(?5.$5:)                : same as above for group 5
(?6.$6:)                : same as above for group 6
....... as many as you need
.doc"                   : literally
$0                     : a space then content of group 0 (ie. the whole match)
```

**Given an input like:**

```
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc-Name="PCP0001 Protocol abc def ghi jkl" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc-Name="PCR0001 Report xyz" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc-Name="DCR0002 Review" group="FP Team"
```

**Result:**

```
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/PCP0001.Protocol.abc.def.ghi.jkl.doc" Doc-Name="PCP0001 Protocol abc def ghi jkl" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/PCR0001.Report.xyz.doc" Doc-Name="PCR0001 Report xyz" group="FP Team"
Masterfile="DM.xml" Doc="http://1.1.1.1/DCR0002.Review.doc" Doc-Name="DCR0002 Review" group="FP Team"
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out....lol

As barlop pointed out (thanks), this problem is easier after breaking it down into a couple of steps.

Step 1.  Add the Doc="URL" component as explained in the OP

Step 2.  This is a multi-step

Find:
Doc=(\".*)\s(.*.doc")

Replace:
Doc=\1.\2

Use replace all under NotePad++ but use it as many times as needed to replace out all of the spaces.

DONE!

Comment: You asked about dealing with a REPEATING PATTERN  I  One space is obviously no problem. So you didn't ask about what you wanted. A repeating pattern would be doc="abc def ghi"  like a pattern of    non-spaces spaces  repeated, and you want to just delete spaces from it.  What you asked was more technical than what you wanted.  And what you meant to ask is so obvious as to be not really useful to people and so specific that it's only really for your specific case, thus no use for the site